# Flutter - How can I change the background color of LicensePage?

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

I'd like to set the background colour of every screen except `LicensePage` to some colour, so I've specified the `scaffoldBackbroundColor` via the `theme` argument of `MaterialApp` as follows.

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade200),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

This changes the background colour of the licences page too, so in order to change it back to white, I tried overriding `scaffoldBackbroundColor`, but it did not work.

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('Show licenses'),
            onPressed: () => showLicensePage(context: context),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this and it worked successfully.

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
      child: const Text('Show licenses'),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute<void>(
          builder: (context) => Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: LicensePage(...),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: `LicensePage` was changed to use `cardColor` instead of `scaffoldBackgroundColor` for the background colour. See [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63475) and [the related PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/64639).

Answer (score 6):

In my case I found ThemeData(cardColor) was dictating the LicensePage background color. So,

```
showLicense(BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      builder: (context) => Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          cardColor: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        child: LicensePage(
          applicationVersion: '0.1',
          applicationIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
          applicationLegalese: 'Legal stuff',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Setting the cardColor property was the only one that did the trick for me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This way you cannot set the theme, set color using `Container`

```
 Scaffold(
        body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Show licenses'),
              onPressed: () => showLicensePage(context: context),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Which scaffold? Setting it to Scaffold of HomeScreen didn't work, and to make matters worse, it changed the background colour of the home screen to white, which I don't want.

Comment: @kaboc: Edited the answer, try that

Comment: Did you try it yourself? It does not work. FYI, `ColoredBox` can be used instead of `Container` to change the colour of a widget in newer versions of Flutter.

Comment: I wonder how come it can work. LicensePage is another screen opened from HomeScreen, so I doubt changing the colour of the content in HomeScreen affects the background colour of LicensePage.